# Matlab function output , should be simple

Tags: matlab, for-loop, output

So i have a 1xn matrix x and the for loop calculates the absolute value of differences in consecutive entries of x starting with entry 3.

```
n=length(x);
for i=3:n
    y=abs(x(i)-x(i-1));
```

what i need my output to be is a 2 column vector. First column displays x and second column displays zeros for the first two rows followed by the results of the for loop.

x is a loaded vector

this is my function 
    function [ z ] = dome(x)

```
n=length(x);
z = zeros(n, 2);
for i=3:n;

z(3:n,2)=abs(x(i)-x(i-1));
z(:,1) = x;


end
```

I'm getting this as output

ans =

1.000000000000000                   0
   1.500000000000000                   0
   1.286953767623375   0.000009575517218
   1.402540803539578   0.000009575517218
   1.345458374023294   0.000009575517218
   1.375170252816038   0.000009575517218
   1.360094192761733   0.000009575517218
   1.367846967592133   0.000009575517218
   1.363887003884021   0.000009575517218
   1.365916733390040   0.000009575517218
   1.364878217193677   0.000009575517218
   1.365410061169957   0.000009575517218
   1.365137820669213   0.000009575517218
   1.365277208524479   0.000009575517218
   1.365205850297047   0.000009575517218
   1.365242383718839   0.000009575517218
   1.365223680225282   0.000009575517218
   1.365233255742500   0.000009575517218

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. The code uses the matlab's `diff` function.

```
x = rand(1,10)   % vector of 1x10

y = [x' [0 ; abs(diff(x))']];
y(1:3,:) = [];
```

This gives

> y =
>
> ```
> 0.0462    0.2308
> 0.0971    0.0510
> 0.8235    0.7263
> 0.6948    0.1286
> 0.3171    0.3777
> 0.9502    0.6331
> 0.0344    0.9158
> ```

---

If you want to keep the for loop, this code

```
Y = zeros(length(x), 2); %create the output matrix Y
Y(1:2, 1) = x(1:2);      %popualte the first 2 row of column 1 with x(1:2) // thanks to @Dan

for i=3:length(x);
    Y(i, 1) = x(i);             %populate the first column
    Y(i, 2) = abs(x(i)-x(i-1)); %populate the second column
end
```

gives

> Y =
>
> ```
> 0.7513         0
> 0.2551         0
> 0.5060    0.2509
> 0.6991    0.1931
> 0.8909    0.1918
> 0.9593    0.0684
> 0.5472    0.4121
> 0.1386    0.4086
> 0.1493    0.0107
> 0.2575    0.1082
> ```

Comment: I'm definitely gonna need the for loop in there because im just using the difference as a simpler function. I will need to calculate error estimates in a sequence. Do you know how i could get the results of the for loop into a matrix?

Comment: I suggest you add `Y(1:2, 1) = x(1:2);` before the loop for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB there is a "big" difference between `0` and `0.0000`. The former is really zero while the latter can be almost as big as `0.00005`. You can "fix" it by changing the output format with `format long`. You also need to use `i` in the assignment ...

```
format long;
n=length(x);
z = zeros(n, 2);
z(:,1) = x;
for i=3:n;
  z(i,2)=abs(x(i)-x(i-1));
end
```

Comment: I did format long and this was my output. It used only the final iteration as the value for 2nd column